# Client recognition by ip

Tags: java, javascript, ip, personalization, clientip

I want to track the clients that visits my site, and save them by IP.
That way, next time he will visit my site I could customize my site to match is needs and make it more personal.

One of my problems is that the clients IP is constantly changing....
Is there a way to combine all the client IPs together?
Is there a better way to recognize a client?

Thanks

Comment: The "Usual" way is to create a cookie, as the IP may not be unique (you will potentially get the ip of a router) and the users IP will change if the connection is reset (unless this is an inhouse app when you can controll ip addresses).

Comment: Better approach is to have the user sign-in and then add their preferences

Comment: You can't identify a person by IP. Technically you can track down an IP to a specific customer of an ISP at a given time, but that customer may be an office with hundreds of employees, a public Wifi point in a store, etc. And at a different time, that IP may be assigned to another customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that doesn't have a 100% solution unless you have them work with you by providing a login.  Then you can customize by user.

If that option is off the table then there are other ways you can track people.

- You can use your own cookies. But they can clear their cache.
- You can use advertisers cookies.  But that likely won't be enough info
- You can use ips. but their IP will likely change.
- You can use user agent string.  but that will also likely change over time

You use combinations of these to try to provide a match to your user, but I doubt any of these will be 100% effective.  Especially as your website grows, then you'll get false matches by the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Best solution is to work with them by having a username/password so that they can login and get access to their profile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using cookies? You can find out about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)